# Is every data type in ANSI SQL sortable?

Tags: sql, database, sorting, sql-order-by, ansi-sql

Can I use an `ORDER BY` clause with any SQL data type?

For example, will the query

```
SELECT Column1
FROM TableName
ORDER BY Column1
```

return results, no matter the data type of Column1, grouping columns excluded?

Comment: At least all pre-defined data types. (When it comes to structured user-defined types, you need to create an ordering. And JSON ordering is an optional feature.)

Comment: No. BLOBs, records are not.

Comment: I don't know if even BOOLEAN is guaranteed to be sortable by the SQL standard.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, boolean is sortable. TRUE > FALSE.

Comment: BLOB, CLOB, XML, JSON, ARRAY. But for XML/JSON/ARRAY you can extract elements and sort those. Geometric or Geospatial (point, line, polygon) aren't designed for comparisons and  hence might not be sort-able

Comment: @3N1GM4 I do not have an underlying issue that I am working on. I am simply curious.